# Query varbinary bit field

Tags: sql, binary, bit-manipulation

I am storing which lines in a source file are executed in a SQL server database. In my query I want to determine if two file's executions overlap; e.g.

```
Line Run1 Run2
1    x
2    x    x
3
4         x
```

Run1 executed lines 1 and 2, run2 lines 2 and 4. I can see by doing a (run1 & ! run2) that line 1 was executed in Run1 only.

If I store the runs as bit masks (varbinary) how can I compare runs in an SQL query?

```
create table runs columns filename varchar, runCoverage varbinary;
select filename, andNot(run, 1) from runs group by filename
```

This would compare a (selection of) run with the others run bit fields. Ideally I want to OR the bitfields of groups of records (line coverage data from one component) and then AND NOT with another group of records. I can count the 1 bits in the result, which would be the number of lines covered in one group of tests but not in another...

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines isn't too great, you could simply cast the varbinary to a bigint to do bitwise comparissons
to get all files that executed line 1:

```
where (cast(runCoverage as bigint) & 1) > 0
```

or all files that executed any line beside line 1

```
where (cast(runCoverage as bigint) & ~1) > 0
```

If the  number of lines is higher, some helper function could be made using substr to get the proper bits. Then again, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question alltogether.

Comment: Good to see a sql developer who is not afraid of bitmasking.

Comment: My bit field represent files, that can be thousands of lines.